# Handle User Session Logout Time With Authentication Forms

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have `session` table in database where datetime values of `login` and `logout` are `stored`. In my `MVC` application I am using `authentication Forms`. Where the cookie is `persistent` for example 20 minutes with `slidingExpiration = true`. What is the good practice to `ping` the `session` in `database` and to set accurate `logout time`. For example when the slidingExpiration `fires` and `reset` the `expire` time of cookie to `plus` 20 minutes in the same session key. How to `handle` this in databse to `update` the logout time of user session ? My end point is to keep accurate logout time of user session in database.

**Web.config**

```
<forms loginUrl="/KJH/Account/SignIn" protection="All" timeout="20" name="FedCookie" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="/NCB/Home/Index" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
```

**SQL script to update user session**

```
UPDATE dbo.tSession SET LogoutTime = DATEADD(mi, 20, GETDATE()) WHERE Ukey = @Session and LogoutTime > GETDATE()
```